# Opentok video view is not connected for 1 user

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, videochat, tokbox

Hi I am using opentok in my iOS app, I have implemented the codes as what explained in their doc.
The session do created and the call go connected. In the device of user1 - both publisher and subscriber views are visible. But in user2  device subscriber view is not visible. This indicates there are some issues with publishing in the user1 side.

There is the report I am getting in user1 side.

```
     connectWithSubscriberToken

     ------------------------------------------------
     OpenTok iOS Library, Rev.2
     This build was born on Oct  9 2014 at 15:39:11
     Version: 2.3.1.5D747E70-ios
     libOpenTokObjC:a95b84edc2a3a1e2b4cb4bc2092cb90ca43cbb05
     libOTKit:31f8dbf14c1ae37b9c95d5b2d83fd6c737d89f72
     WebRTC:7113
     Copyright 2014 TokBox, Inc.
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    ------------------------------------------------
     WARNING[OpenTok]: Failed to set mode video chat 
    sessionDidConnect: 1_MX40NTA1MDkzMn5-MTQxNTA0NDk0OTQyNX4vN3RpYkh4bjhoZ2ljdVRhWSszMTZnTi9-UH4
    - connectionId: 5306CAA5-6E53-4C7E-82E1-DCE36E241401
    - creationTime: 46810-12-28 4:31:19 am +0000
   subscriberDidConnectToStream (A0E7068F-6EEE-4C46-B29E-084AD2673541)
   screenheight 1024.000000
   navheight 44.000000
   subscriberVideoDataReceived (C09FED83-2586-4636-8DF3-B23A59BCC84A)
```

I have gone through opentok forum complaining about this issue [here](https://forums.tokbox.com/ios/warning-failed-to-set-mode-video-chat-t44216) and [here](https://forums.tokbox.com/ios/sdk-2-2-session-streamcreated-not-fired-for-receiver-t43864).

**WARNING[OpenTok]: Failed to set mode video chat**

Anybody faced this issue ?
Please help me to fix this.